# What does it mean to "invoke NSViewController" (before creating it)?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nsviewcontroller

In [the NSViewController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434481-init), it says:

> If you pass in a nil for nibNameOrNil then nibName will return nil and loadView() will throw an exception; in this case you must invoke NSViewController before [Creating A View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsviewcontroller#1662069) is invoked, or override loadView().

"Creating A View Controller" links to NSViewController's init() method.

What does it mean to invoke a class, before initializing it?  I've been using AppKit for over 10 years and I can't make heads or tails of this sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation of Xcode 6 the text is:

> If you pass in a nil for nibNameOrNil then nibName will return nil and loadView will throw an exception; in this case you must invoke setView: before view is invoked, or override loadView.

"setView:" links to the NSViewController class.
"view" links to the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method of NSViewController.
Apparently Apple adjusted the text to the links instead of the other way around.